# Ionic component not working in Ionic tab page

Tags: angular, ionic3

I need some help.
I have declared a component; the component works fine when I use it on a normal page in Ionic.
When I try to use the same component in Ionic tab page; I get the error message

1. If 'vehicle-details' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'vehicle-details' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

   [ERROR ->]

I have declared it in component.module.ts
I have looked around and can’t seem to figure out what is causing this issue.

### app.module.ts

```
import {
  ComponentsModule
} from '../components/components.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [ComponentsModule],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

### components.module.ts

```
import {
  NgModule
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ReactiveFormsModule
} from '@angular/forms';
import {
  IonicModule
} from 'ionic-angular';

import {
  VehicleDetailsComponent
} from './pages/vehicle-details/vehicle-details';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    VehicleDetailsComponent  ],
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(LoginComponent)
  ],
  exports: [
    VehicleDetailsComponent  ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

Comment: Do you mind to show us yout module.app.ts? You are not lazy loading Right?

Comment: I have edited the question and the component is not being lazy loaded.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution; I used the CLI to create the tab pages, The CLI did not declare the pages in app.module.ts.
After declaring the pages in app.module.ts, I able to use the component.